# How to update tweets using Twitter 4J?

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am using Twitter4J (2.1.0) to try to update tweets.  I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

In particular my problems are:

***(a) Not all tweets post successfully. I often get the error code of -1.  According to a google group [post](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter4j/browse_thread/thread/9beafa9dd7e2c43d?fwc=1)...***

> You get code -1 when the internal http component fails to connect to
>   or read from the API.  You may also get code -1 when the API is
>   unreachable from the JVM due to the DNS related issues.

Strangely I seemed to be getting this pretty much every second post.  To deal with this whenever I received the -1 error code I would try to update again. While I realise this is not a very good solution. this fixed the probem 95% of the time

***(b) I get a duplication errors (error code 403) whenever the new tweet matches any old tweet***

Error code 403 occurs even if the duplicate is now outdated (eg. post "Hello there", post a variety of status updates, then post "Hello there" again throws a TwitterException with error code 403)

***My current code...***

My code is in an AsyncTask which is in turn in a Service (rather than activity). I have included the Asynctask code and another method below....

```
    class SendTwitAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String tokenTwit = params[0];
        String tokenSecretTwit = params[1];
        String strMessageBody = params[2];

        AccessToken aToken = new AccessToken(tokenTwit, tokenSecretTwit);

        // initialize Twitter4J
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(aToken);


        // create a tweet
        // strMessageBody varies
        String tweet = strMessageBody;




        boolean bool = twitter.isOAuthEnabled();

        if (twitter.isOAuthEnabled()) {
            GeoLocation geolocation = new GeoLocation(-33.91, 151.25);
            try {

                twitter.updateStatus(tweet, geolocation);
                showNotification("Twitter One" , TWIT_SUCCESS); 

            } catch (TwitterException te) {

                if (te.getStatusCode() == -1) {
                    //try again
                    try {
                        twitter.updateStatus(tweet, geolocation);

                        showNotification("Twitter Two ", TWIT_SUCCESS);
                    } 
                    catch (TwitterException tetwo) {
                        describeTwitException(tetwo.getStatusCode());
                    }       
                } //end if

                //else exception other than -1
                else {
                    describeTwitException(te.getStatusCode());
                } //end else

            }// end outer catch
        } //end if
        else {
            showNotification("Unable to authenticate" , TWIT_FAIL);
        }//
        return null;
    }



} //end class SendTwitAsyncTask

public void describeTwitException(int twitExceptionCode) {
    switch (twitExceptionCode) {

    case (-1):
        showNotification("Twitter (unable to connect)", TWIT_FAIL);
        break;
    case(403):
        showNotification("Twitter (duplicate tweet)", TWIT_FAIL);
        break;
    default:
        showNotification("Twitter", TWIT_FAIL);

    } //end switch
}  //end describeTwitException method
```

Answer (score 1):

The twitter API will reject any tweet that matches a tweet that you've already made.  I don't think the old tweet ever 'expires.'

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.  I tried sending duplicate tweets from Twitter's android app. It would not let me send duplicate tweets that were recently in my timeline. However, whenever the original tweets were very old (eg. greater than a year), duplicate tweets would post successfully.  PS. Voted your answer up but left question open as still unsure why I am getting the -1 error code status.